Import and use already existing SSL certificates with new Tomcat instance
I had to completely to re-install Tomcat server using new hardware but I have certificates from Certificate Authority which was used in previous installation:

Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA /* signing CA */
USERTrust RSA Certification Authority /* root CA */
AAA Certificate Services

Is it possible to use those cetificates again or shall I buy new?
If I can use the cetificates again please guide me how to import them because as I understood it must be coupled with private key from new installation.
Thank you!

This is not about programming or development and thus offtopic, and you aren't entirely clear, but: if the names you list are the cert issuers and the name(s) in subject AND SAN of the first cert (still) match your server, then you can use the existing cert chain IF it hasn't expired and you use the SAME privatekey NOT a new one. If you create a new privatekey you MUST get a new certificate. (And if you're using a hardware-based key and the hardware either is lost or damaged or can't be used on the new computer you will have to create a new key.) ...

... But according to the Sectigo website, if the term you paid for hasn't expired (which can be longer than the term of the specific certificate previously issued) you can get a new certificate -- they call it 'reissued' -- on that previous payment. If you are able to move the existing key AND certs to the new system, configuring them in tomcat is probably suitable for superuser.com and maybe security.stackexchange.com -- but may well be duplicate, so look first.

You can definitely re-use them anywhere until they expire. You will definitely need the original private key generated before the previous CSR you used to obtain the certificate. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

@JohnWilliams, I have CSR from previous installation and read many times  tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html - but how to reuse it?

You don't need to use the CSR. You need to find the private key generated in a keypair that was used to create the CSR. The key is not in the CSR but it will be on the old machine that has Tomcat on. It's usually in a .pem or .keystore file in %TOMCAT_HOME%/conf. Look in the old TC server.xml Connectors/Connector for the scheme="https" connector should lead you there.

I am assuming that the old Tomcat server has a still readable disk or a backup exists. If you don't and don't have a copy of the private key and certificate then you will have to buy a new cert.
You can copy the private key and certificate from the old Tomcat server to the new one.
On the old machine open the file %TOMCAT_HOME%/conf/server.xml and find the Connector definition where the SSLEnabled="true". There you will find paths to the files containing key and certificates.
Copy these files to the new machine and edit its server.xml to point at the copied files.
That's it.
